# Simplest way to check if key exists in object using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In CoffeeScript, what is the simplest way to check if a key exists in an object?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
key of obj
```

This compiles to JavaScript's `key in obj`. (CoffeeScript uses `of` when referring to keys, and `in` when referring to array values: `val in arr` will test whether `val` is in `arr`.)

thejh's answer is correct if you want to ignore the object's prototype. Jimmy's answer is correct if you want to ignore keys with a `null` or `undefined` value.

Comment: most likely `own key of obj` works, too, to aditionally test `.hasOwnProperty()`. the “most likely” comes from me not having tried, but this syntax working in comprehensions.

Comment: @flyingsheep No, it only works in comprehensions. Try it: http://coffeescript.org/#try:own%20key%20of%20obj

Comment: ah, [ok](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1019): `own = (prop, obj) -> Object::hasOwnProperty.call obj, prop`

Answer (score 38):

The '?' operator checks for existence:

```
if obj?
    # object is not undefined or null

if obj.key?
    # obj.key is not undefined or null

# call function if it exists
obj.funcKey?()

# chain existence checks, returns undefined if failure at any level
grandChildVal = obj.key?.childKey?.grandChildKey

# chain existence checks with function, returns undefined if failure at any level
grandChildVal = obj.key?.childKey?().grandChildKey
```

Comment: This fails if the key is there but has a value of `null`.

Comment: In the case where one doesn't care about the key existing but being null, then `obj.key?` is probably the most concise.

Answer (score 22):

```
obj.hasOwnProperty(name)
```

(to ignore inherited properties)

Comment: I like this response because `key of obj` will throw an error if the value is a string or number. `Cannot use 'in' operator to search`.

In this case if the object is not undefined and not null it will work.

Comment: This fails where the object has the value from its prototype.